# svn update and resolve

Tags: svn

I've got a folder under svn control. It may contain some modifications that may be conflicting with the working copy. I want to do

```
svn up --accept=theirs-full
```

but svn version is too old and doesn't suport 'accept' option. Is there an easy workaround for that except updating subversion? Version installed in there is 1.4

Basically, I want to update a folder and revert all conflicting changes while leaving other changes intact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `svn up --non-interactive` to update and leave everything conflicted then revert everything with a conflict afterwards.

If you're on Unix, you can use `svn st |gawk '/^C/ {print $2}'` to list all conflicting files then `svn st |gawk '/^C/ {print $2}' |xargs svn revert` or similar (untested) to actually do the revert.

If you're on Windows, I can't think of an easy way to do this without grep / sed / awk, sorry. If you do have one of those but not xargs then it's easy to turn a list of filenames into a command line using e.g. the visual studio editor (alt-drag to trim off the Cs then delete at the end of each line to build up a list).

Comment: I ended up doing that. Was hoping there's another svn command I'm not aware of that can do the trick in one blow.

Answer (score 0):

Why not update your client?  The new clients (latest is currently 1.6.12) will continue working fine with older servers.

Also, we're running server version 1.4.5 and `--accept` works okay for us.

Comment: I've got 1.4.4 on linux. Updating it pulls lots of dependancies and then fails to resolve some of them. Considering the fact that server got other stuff running and I know little about what it relies on, I don't feel comfortable about the update.
If it was windows I would've certainly done that.